# How to set timezone for SQL?

Tags: sql, datetime, sqlite, hosting, timezone

I'm using SQLite for my cgi application, but the timezone I'm in is different from that of the shared server this stuff is running on. Can I set my timezone somehow in SQLite so I don't need to mess up my application with time conversions and I can use things like NOW() in my SQL? If not: what are my other options?

Comment: I think this is different. As I said: I don't want to mess up my application code and I'm not using SQLite directly (and don't want to). I'm using Elixir for accessing the database.

Comment: Your application is exactly the right place for converting a UTC time into a local time for user consumption. This is a presentation concern similar to the date format itself, and it should absolutely not touch the database layer. Backend time values should always always always be UTC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a way to set the connection time zone because it's targeted towards embedded database uses--whatever you use to change your C library localtime() output should work for SQLite. This works for me on MacOS:

```
$ TZ=America/New_York sqlite3 dbfile "select datetime('now','localtime');"
2010-01-06 09:53:28

$ TZ=America/Los_Angeles sqlite3 dbfile "select datetime('now','localtime');"
2010-01-06 06:53:41
```