# How to Set timezone in session of SQLite?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, session, datetime, timezone

In MySql following query is used to set session

```
set @@session.time_zone='+05:00';
```

But it is not working into SQLite.

As on following link, It is not possible to set session in SQLite:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013542/how-to-set-timezone-for-sql
```

We can select time according to zone as given in following query:

select DateTime('now','-5.30 hours');

but it is not useful to set timezone in session.

So Is there any way to set timezone in session of SQLite when executing any select/insert query?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite times use UTC by default, and can be converted between UTC and the current local time with the `localtime` and `utc` modifiers of the [date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).
However, the difference between UTC and the local time is read from the operating system, and cannot be changed.